# Select из БД без обращения к сущности Typeorm

Tags: javascript, база-данных, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Пытаюсь получить данные из таблицы без создания сущности в бд таким образом:

`const resultQuery = getManager().createQueryBuilder().select('что-то там...').from('из такой-то таблицы')`

Однако, возникает такая ошибка:

`ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection \"default\" was not found.\n    at ConnectionManager.get`

Как можно вытащить данные из таблиц без создания entity?

Comment: В чем тогда смысл использования orm?

Comment: Хорошо, не подскажете, как тогда в коде можно вытащить данные из бд?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/postgresql/single-server/connect-nodejs